# Checking tables for null returns 0 regardless

Tags: sql

I don't understand why this query doesn't work.

I have a table which is full of rows where 3 of the column values are set to `NULL`.

But when I run the following query, it returns 0 (it should return 96)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SEAT WHERE BOOKED=null;
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `where booked is null`.  Almost every comparison to `NULL` returns `NULL`, which is treated as false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your database settings and the specific RDBMS you are using, but if you are using ANSI NULL syntax you cannot directly compare a value to NULL with an equality test (`=`) -- it will always fail.

Use `WHERE BOOKED IS NULL` instead.

Comment: That worked like a charm. I feel stupid now. Thanks though! I'll accept when it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `IS NULL` instead of `= null`

Since null technically isn't a value, you can't compare null using the `=` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Use `IS NULL`

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM SEAT
WHERE BOOKED IS NULL
```